# What is a good way to have a 2d battle royal circle with an adjustable center and radius in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, mask

I am having trouble creating a battle royal zone in unity. I want it to be translucent and cover the map with a masked circle in the middle. However, I dont know if there is any way to control the radius of this mask which is something I need to do regularly. Does anyone know how to achive these results?
*It should look like the the map view from Fortnite BR.(https://assets.rockpapershotgun.com/images/2019/01/fortnite-small-storm-690x388.jpg/RPSS/resize/690x-1/format/jpg/)*

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve this effect.

The first and easiest is using [the built in Mask](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-Mask.html), if you are using UI to render the minimap. You can also create a custom UI mesh, as [described here](https://saticmotion.github.io/Blog/2018/06/26/Generating-UI-Meshes-in-Unity.html) for example.

The last option is a (custom) shader. You can download the built-in [shaders here](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive) and copy over the UI one. Then you have to add your own logic to the fragment shader, something that looks for the Length of the distance of the current UV coordinates and the circle, and if thats smaller than the radius it must be inside. In that case, either [clip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-clip) or set the alpha to 0.